# Ubuntu & wireless network - does not connect

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04, wireless-router

Tried the live boot of Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on my work PC today (it has Windows Vista on it and it is literally DEAD slow). There's a wireless network in the office and the PC has a wireless network card installed.
The problem was the following - I booted up Ubuntu, the "tray" was showing the network icon. I click on it, it shows me the list of all available wireless networks. I click on the one that belongs to our office, enter the password, click "Connect".

Now, here comes the problem - after "loading" for some three minutes, the same window pops back up. No errors, no messages, absolutely nothing. The password is correct because the Windows installation and the other PCs in the office can connect just fine.

Anyone knows what could be the problem? The drivers are apparently fine if it can find the networks and detect the connection encryption correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you should google "ubuntu live CD wifi connection" that will drive you to the [ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/) and check as well the [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) site.

Comment: Well, doesn't matter anymore, got the Windows installation up and running smooth enough. This is just a temporary PC so I won't bother much about getting it to run perfectly.